# Cracking a hash when you know the result?

Tags: hash, salt

If I know that the algorithm used is SHA1 constructed as `salt+key`, and I have the result, is it possible to find the salt?

Example:

```
sha1(saltExamplealturkovic) => 4e6a306ff65e252571f36972949f45e513b79ba7
```

In this example, I know that the input value is `alturkovic`, the result is `4e6a306ff65e252571f36972949f45e513b79ba7`, how it is constructed and that SHA1 is used as the hashing algorithm. I would like to find out what salt was used (with some common sense limits of course, such as length).

I tried using `hashcat` but I can't figure out if this can even be done using such a tool...

Comment: In theory the usual tools could be changed to also brute-force salts given passwords, but salts are usually chosen uniformly at random from a space of size $\geq 2^{64}$ so there's little hope that they can be recovered by brute-force and there are no structural weaknesses (usually) that allow a faster recovery (except if the salt is encoded into the stored hash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Salts are too long to try and brute force them.

---

### In theory

You can create a [mask attack](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mask_attack) using hashcat, specifically a [hybrid attack](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=hybrid_attack).

Let's assume you know that the salt used is (only) 4 numbers.

```
-a 7 ?d?d?d?d myKnownKey.txt
```

myKnownKey.txt contains the key `alturkovic`.

This setup would then try out these combinations:

- 0000alturkovic
- 0001alturkovic
- 0002alturkovic
- $\ldots$
- 9999alturkovic

This is one example of how to create hybrid attacks using hashcat.

---

### In practice

In practice salts are (as SEJPM commented) of course not only just 4 digits long but they are very long random alphanumerical characters and thus renders any brute force attacks impractical.

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I was looking for. I am aware of the caveats and downsides and I have reasonable expectations for this to work. I have to try this tomorrow when I get to work to see how performant it actually is. Thank you.

Comment: I am having some trouble setting this up, I created a `hash.txt` file containing `4e6a306ff65e252571f36972949f45e513b79ba7` and the wordlist containing `alturkovic`. I then tried running it like this: `hashcat64.exe -m 120 -a 7 ?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a -o output.txt hash.txt wordlist.txt` but it won't load the hash, I am getting: `Hash '?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a': Separator unmatched
No hashes loaded.`, I assume I am using something wrong but can't figure out what, any idea?

Comment: Another practical method: [Google it!](https://www.google.com/search?q=4e6a306ff65e252571f36972949f45e513b79ba7)